# Cloned production SQL Server now Windows Authentication doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, authentication, connectivity

I needed to create a test environment for one of our applications that uses SQL Server as its data store. Our sysadmin cloned the existing production server to create the test server.

I can connect to SQL Server on the test server using Windows Authentication, but not the production server (I can connect to production using a SQL login). I could connect to the production server using Windows Authentication before it was cloned.

Here is the error message:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

What can I do to connect using Windows Authentication again?

SQL Server 2008 R2 version: 10.50.2550.0

Some more info...

- All of our servers are virtual (using VMware)
- This same situation has happened with another production SQL Server. Again, we made a clone of production for a test environment. As with this case, I'm able to connect to that SQL Server using Windows Auth.

Sean brings up a good point about invalid SPNs, but what I don't understand is why SQL Auth. would work if it was cloned improperly?

Comment: Sounds like it was cloned improperly and now you are getting hit by invalid SPNs - most likely from having the server names be the same even if in DNS it is different. Check AD with your AD admin. I could be wrong, but that's where I'd start given the error.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to follow up on monday at work.

Comment: Was the machine SID changed in the clone?  If not, Active Directory will only allow the most recently booted machine to authenticate users.

Comment: Agree with Max. Cloning a server and not giving it a new SID will definitely cause it to conflict with the current PROD server.  I would advise doing this sort of thing in an environment separate from production.

Comment: Nope...the SID was never changed. That has to be it. If someone wants to provide an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

If the machine SID was not changed Active Directory will only allow the most recently booted machine to authenticate users.

Cloning a server and not giving it a new SID will definitely cause it to conflict with the current PROD server. I would advise doing this sort of thing in an environment separate from production.